# Is there a severity ranking for ESLint errors?

Tags: javascript, eslint, ranking

I am currently analyzing different code packages. I am using **ESLint** to check the code quality.

After analyzing I get an object with ESLint errors and how often they appeared.

```
"no-multi-assign": 1,
"no-var": 47,
...
"comma-dangle": 133,
"no-shadow": 136,
```

Now I have lots of errors, but can't really rate how severe the errors are.
The single `no-multi-assign` error is certainly more severe than 133 `comma-dangle` errors.

Now the question is, if there is some kind of ranking that gives each ESLint error a severity ranking?
Maybe somebody has an idea how to rank these errors.

Here is a list with [all ESLint rules](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/)

Comment: You can set some rules to only be warnings. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: "Severity" is determined by the ES Lint configuration; there's "off", "warn", and "error" (and IIRC there's been an "info" level requested but doesn't exist still). The "real" severity depends on what the devs care about; just because something happens to have an "error" level doesn't mean it's something that'll *break* something, just that it's been deemed "important to care about"--for a variety of reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ESLint [rules](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/rules) have `0` (`"off"`), `1` (`"warn"`), or `2`(`"error"`), which roughly translates to how 'severe' the rule is.

You can find people publishing their own `eslintrc.json` which you can use as a 'ranking'. An example is [`standard/eslint-config-standard`](https://github.com/standard/eslint-config-standard)

But there won't be any meaningful ranking like `no-console` is more severe than `no-empty` but less severe than `no-labels`, since that's really subjective.